# dynamic array in C++ - Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int tmp = 5;
    int * arr = new int[tmp];
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        if (i == tmp) //if count of values is equal to max size of arr then create new arr with more space
        {
            int * s = new int[tmp]; // reserve memory
            for(int i = 0; i < (tmp); i++)
            {
                s[i] = arr[i]; //fill reserve memory with values from array arr
            }
            delete [] arr; // delete arr array
            tmp *= 2; //twice more space for array
            arr = new int[tmp]; //create new arr with twice more space
            for (int i = 0; i < (tmp / 2); i++)
            {
                arr[i] = s[i]; // add values from old short arr to new arr with more space
            }
            delete [] s; // delete reserve memory
        }
        arr[i] = 1; //add 1 to position i in array
    }
    //show array
    for (int j = 0; j < tmp; j++)
        cout << arr[j] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    delete [] arr; //delete arr
    return 0;
}
```

And I do not understand this error from valgrind:

```
==2664== 
==2664== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2664==    at 0x4EBFCDE: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==2664==    by 0x4EC02BC: std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==2664==    by 0x4ECC06D: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==2664==    by 0x400AE1: main (in /home/vojta/Dokumenty/C++/vstup do pole/a.out)
==2664==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==2664==    at 0x4C2B800: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2664==    by 0x400A2D: main (in /home/vojta/Dokumenty/C++/vstup do pole/a.out)
==2664== 
==2664== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==2664==    at 0x4EBFBC3: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==2664==    by 0x4EBFD05: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==2664==    by 0x4EC02BC: std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==2664==    by 0x4ECC06D: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==2664==    by 0x400AE1: main (in /home/vojta/Dokumenty/C++/vstup do pole/a.out)
==2664==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==2664==    at 0x4C2B800: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2664==    by 0x400A2D: main (in /home/vojta/Dokumenty/C++/vstup do pole/a.out)
==2664== 
==2664== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2664==    at 0x4EBFBCF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==2664==    by 0x4EBFD05: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==2664==    by 0x4EC02BC: std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==2664==    by 0x4ECC06D: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==2664==    by 0x400AE1: main (in /home/vojta/Dokumenty/C++/vstup do pole/a.out)
==2664==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==2664==    at 0x4C2B800: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2664==    by 0x400A2D: main (in /home/vojta/Dokumenty/C++/vstup do pole/a.out)
==2664== 
==2664== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2664==    at 0x4EBFD33: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==2664==    by 0x4EC02BC: std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==2664==    by 0x4ECC06D: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==2664==    by 0x400AE1: main (in /home/vojta/Dokumenty/C++/vstup do pole/a.out)
==2664==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==2664==    at 0x4C2B800: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2664==    by 0x400A2D: main (in /home/vojta/Dokumenty/C++/vstup do pole/a.out)
==2664== 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
==2664== 
==2664== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2664==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2664==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 80 bytes allocated
==2664== 
==2664== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==2664== 
==2664== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2664== ERROR SUMMARY: 12 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I find out that if I run this cycle

```
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
```

to 10 not only to 7, valgrind do not show any errors.
I want to ask you, if my idea of having some positions in array empty, is wrong? I do not know if my code is correct for creating array depending on how much values you want to add. Does it exist some other ways, how to create larger array if you need it?

I tried to run valgrind with --track-origins=yes but couldn't find answer in it.

I'm new to C++, so I'm happy for every new ideas or hints.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once this array grows to five `int`, the shown code grows it to ten elements, and proceeds to add two additional `int`s, #5 and #6, to the array (I am using 0-based indexes to refer to the individual `int`s in the array).

The for loop at the end will attempt to print all 10 values of the array. Including the uninitialized values, #7 through #9. That's what valgrind is telling you.

valgrind's diagnostic is nearly undecipherable because uninitialized memory usage doesn't actually occur until you're deep in the bowels of the I/O library. The bug is in the `main()` function, but all it does is pass a reference to an uninitialized value to the I/O library. That doesn't trigger undefined behavior until the uninitialized value is actually grabbed inside the I/O library, for formatting.

P.S.: the array is grown first by copying the contents of the array to a new `s` array. The original `arr` gets deleted and replaced by the new 10 element `arr`, then the five values get copied back from `s` and `s` gets deleted.

This is a lot of unnecessary copying. It's sufficient to allocate the new 10 element array, copy the existing contents to it, then delete the original, and replace it with the new array.

Comment: I changed code in for loop,
so now it works without errors, thank you. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Your question has been answered already, but next time, know that if you compile your code with the `-g3` flag in `g++`, valgrind will also show you line numbers that the problems occurred. For example, compile with `g++ teste.cpp -g3` and `valgrind --track-origins=yes ./a.out` will give you:

```
==20609== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==20609== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==20609== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==20609== Command: ./a.out
==20609== 
==20609== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==20609==    at 0x4F3CCAE: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==20609==    by 0x4F3CEDC: std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==20609==    by 0x4F493F9: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==20609==    by 0x400AE0: main (teste.cpp:31)
==20609==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==20609==    at 0x4C2E80F: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20609==    by 0x400A2B: main (teste.cpp:20)
==20609== 
==20609== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==20609==    at 0x4F3BB13: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==20609==    by 0x4F3CCD9: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==20609==    by 0x4F3CEDC: std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==20609==    by 0x4F493F9: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==20609==    by 0x400AE0: main (teste.cpp:31)
==20609==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==20609==    at 0x4C2E80F: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20609==    by 0x400A2B: main (teste.cpp:20)
==20609== 
==20609== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==20609==    at 0x4F3BB1F: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==20609==    by 0x4F3CCD9: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==20609==    by 0x4F3CEDC: std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==20609==    by 0x4F493F9: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==20609==    by 0x400AE0: main (teste.cpp:31)
==20609==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==20609==    at 0x4C2E80F: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20609==    by 0x400A2B: main (teste.cpp:20)
==20609== 
==20609== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==20609==    at 0x4F3CD0C: std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_insert_int<long>(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==20609==    by 0x4F3CEDC: std::num_put<char, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, char, long) const (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==20609==    by 0x4F493F9: std::ostream& std::ostream::_M_insert<long>(long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==20609==    by 0x400AE0: main (teste.cpp:31)
==20609==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==20609==    at 0x4C2E80F: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20609==    by 0x400A2B: main (teste.cpp:20)
==20609== 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
==20609== 
==20609== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20609==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==20609==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 4 frees, 73,808 bytes allocated
==20609== 
==20609== LEAK SUMMARY:
==20609==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20609==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20609==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20609==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==20609==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20609== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==20609== 
==20609== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==20609== ERROR SUMMARY: 12 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

This tells you that the uninitialised values where used in line 31, and they were created by the new in line 20.

This might be very helpfull.